# \fbox does not work in \headebox baposter

Tags: boxes, baposter

I am doing my poster, I need to put a set of `itemize` in a box.

I can not put the all text but here a portion of my code

```
\fbox{
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{\color{red}{Adaptation of classic VH}}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textit{\textbf{ababababababababababababababababababa}}
\item \textbf{bccncbcncbcncbcncbcncbcncbcncbcnccncbcncbcncbcncbc} \color{green}\textit{ gdgdgdgdgdgdgdgdgdgdgdgdgdg} \color{black}{and} \color{blue}\textit{jdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdjdj}.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize} 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`itemize` is a vertical (par) mode construct but `\fbox` makes a horizontal (LR) box that does not allow line breaks. You need

```
\fbox{\parbox{5cm}{%
\begin{itemize}
...
\end{itemize}}}
```